# How to find nearest week in R

Tags: r, date, date-arithmetic

I want to find the nearest lowest week for each date in df$Upload_Date by referencing a series of weeks called 'weeks'.

```
head(df$Upload_Date)
#[1] "2014-09-25" "2014-09-25" "2014-09-25" "2014-11-06" "2014-09-25" "2014-09-25"
```

I also have a list of weeks that I will be using in a report.

```
> weeks
 [1] "2014-08-01" "2014-08-08" "2014-08-15" "2014-08-22" "2014-08-29" "2014-09-05" "2014-09-12" "2014-09-19" "2014-09-26"
[10] "2014-10-03" "2014-10-10" "2014-10-17" "2014-10-24" "2014-10-31" "2014-11-07" "2014-11-14"
```

The first value in df$Upload_Date is "2014-09-25. The nearest lower week in "weeks" is "2014-09-19". So I want to create a new column called "df$report_week" which will assign "2014-09-19" for the row with "2014-09-25".

I've tried setting the following variables (not sure if this will be helpful or not):

```
upload_day <- as.POSIXlt(df$Upload_Date[1])$yday
> upload_day
[1] 267

report_days <- as.POSIXlt(weeks)$yday
> report_days
 [1] 212 219 226 233 240 247 254 261 268 275 282 289 296 303 310 317
```

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3):

You may try `cut` and use your "week" vector as `breaks`:

```
date <- as.Date(c("2014-09-25", "2014-10-06"))
weeks <- as.Date("2014-08-01") + 7 * 0:10

cut(date, breaks = weeks)
# [1] 2014-09-19 2014-10-03
```

Also note the 'built-in' `breaks` `"weeks"`, where weeks start on Monday (default `start.on.monday = TRUE`), in contrast to your 'start on Friday-weeks':

```
cut(date, breaks = "week")
# [1] 2014-09-22 2014-10-06
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `findInterval`. It looks like you are trying to find the week of your upload dates with the weeks being as of the previous Friday.

```
data.frame(date=Upload_Date,week.of=weeks[findInterval(Upload_Date, weeks)])
```

```
        date    week.of
1 2014-09-25 2014-09-19
2 2014-11-06 2014-10-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `floor_date()` from `lubridate`. E.g., `floor_date(x, unit = "week")`. The other answers with `cut` is very nice for the general case where you have that handy vector of weeks (or whatever other time interval). This would work for most standard units, the choices are `c("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year")`.